# why cant i manage ~382MB of memory when i have it available?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management

**OBJECTIVE: manage a `unsigned long tomBOLA[5][10000000];`**

`$top` gives me:

```
top - 14:05:35 up  4:06,  4 users,  load average: 0.46, 0.48, 0.44
Tasks: 182 total,   1 running, 180 sleeping,   1 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s): 14.4%us,  2.4%sy,  0.0%ni, 82.5%id,  0.6%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   3092064k total,  1574460k used,  1517604k free,   168944k buffers
Swap:  1998840k total,        0k used,  1998840k free,   672756k cached
```

program has, a malloc the size of (5*10000000) * 8bytes =382MB, then fill with 0s and a read of what is stored in tomBOLA:

```
long int **tomBOLA;

if((tomBOLA=(long int **)malloc(5))==NULL){ /*MALLOC()*/
    printf("\n\tMEMORY ERROR-1");
    exit(1);
}
for(i=0;i<5;i++){
    if((tomBOLA[i]=(long int *)malloc(10000000*sizeof(long int)))==NULL){
        printf("\n\tMEMORY ERROR-2");
        exit(1);
    }
}                                          /*MALLOC()*/
for(i=0;i<5;i++){
    for(j=0;j<10000000;j++){
        tomBOLA[i][j]=0;
    }
}                                         /*FILL WITH 0s before using*/
for(i=0;i<5;i++){
    for(j=0;j<10000000;j++){
        printf("%ld ",tomBOLA[i][j]);
    }
printf("\n\n\n\n\n");
}                                         /*CONTROL OF 0s*/
```

gdb gives

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
_int_malloc (av=<value optimized out>, bytes=<value optimized out>) at malloc.c:4708
4708    malloc.c: No such file or directory.
    in malloc.c
(gdb) bt
#0  _int_malloc (av=<value optimized out>, bytes=<value optimized out>) at malloc.c:4708
#1  0x001dfd4c in *__GI___libc_malloc (bytes=40000000) at malloc.c:3660
#2  0x0804ca86 in main ()
(gdb)
```

**about memory, what am i doing or assuming wrong ??**

Comment: The available memory doesn't matter really, as each process has its own virtual memory which the system will or will not put in the physical memory depending on how things are going.

Comment: use bzero to set everything to 0's.

Comment: @nhahtdh not possible, linux(ubuntu)+gcc+other malloc() worked fine so far

Comment: @mf_: Now I am really curious why it can cause a segmentation fault in `malloc`. Of course, people can say accessing things out of bounds will give undefined behaviour, etc., but I still want to know what actually happens here...

Comment: @nhahtdh acording to @unwind was because i wasnt `tomBOLA = malloc(5 * sizeof *tomBOLA);`

Comment: @mf_: I have read that before writing the comment. I don't understand why segmentation fault happens **inside** `malloc` function (I would expect segmentation fault to happen in your `main()` when you write to bad location). I do know about undefined behaviour and its definition, but I am curious about what is happening behind the scene.

Comment: i tried debugging and that was appeared to me, my version is 
`$ gdb -version
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.1-ubuntu
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "i486-linux-gnu".`

Comment: @Magn3s1um bzero is deprecated, better to use memset

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This:

```
tomBOLA=(long int **)malloc(5))
```

is wrong, it's allocating 5 bytes, leading to immediate buffer overrun when you treat it as an array of five pointers (needing probably 20 bytes). You meant:

```
tomBOLA = malloc(5 * sizeof *tomBOLA);
```

to get five pointers to `unsigned long`.

Note that there's no point in doing this dynamically, it's way simpler to just say:

```
unsigned long *tomBOLA[5];
```

Also:

1. [Get rid of the casts of `malloc()`'s return value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169).
2. Stop using magical constants (the solution above makes the `5` go away in the rest of the code, since you can then use `sizeof tomBOLA / sizeof *tomBOLA` in place of `5`).

Comment: @mf_ That's not the same thing. I realize you want five huge arrays, which is why you need five pointers. Five pointers is `unsigned long *tomBOLA[5];`, please note the asterisk in there. Then you can allocate each array with `malloc()`.

Comment: no casts, did as you recomended, works nice, but now i have a small problem, have to allocate manually other `unsigned long tomBOLA[OTHER_val][10000000];`

Comment: Glad to hear it helped. Consider accepting the answer. I showed how to allocate a dynamic array of `unsigned long *`, that's the second code line: just do `unsigned long **arrays = malloc(n * sizeof *arrays);` where `n` is the number of arrays.

Answer (score 2):

Your first malloc is wrong. You need to allocate enough memory for the pointers.

```
if((tomBOLA=(long int **)malloc(5))==NULL){ /*MALLOC()*/
```

should be

```
if((tomBOLA=(long int **)malloc(5 * sizeof *tomBOLA))==NULL){ /*MALLOC()*/
```

(`sizeof *tomBOLA` here would be the same as `sizeof(long int *)` in this case, but it follows the general pattern of `SomeType *p = malloc(sizeof *p)`)

Answer (score 0):

You may well have that memory available but not in a contiguous block which is what the malloc call is trying to give you.

Comment: alternatives to get a `unsigned long tomBOLA[5][10000000];`

Comment: You can use a chained queue instead of an array. It will grow on demand and can get as big as a pointer can address.